# How to rotate 3D Plotly continuous for R shiny App

Tags: r, animation, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to create a constant rotating 3D scatter plotly so that I can put it in my R shiny app. However, I can't seem to get it to constantly rotate (like this: https://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/mBVVyE).
I don't want to save it to an image/gif just directly use in my App. Can anyone provide any help to get it continuously rotating (I have little experience with Python)? I've tried this in the Viewer screen of R studio, but it doesn't rotate there.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)


N <- 100

x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
y <- runif(N,min= 0, max = 100)
z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
luci.frame <- data.frame(x,y,z)




for (i in seq(0,100, by=0.1)){
  cam.zoom = 2
  ver.angle = 0
  graph <- plot_ly()%>%
    add_trace(type = "scatter3d", 
              mode = "markers", 
              data = luci.frame,
              x = ~x, 
              y = ~y, 
              z = ~z) %>%
    layout(scene = list(
      camera = list(
        eye = list(
          x = cos(i)*cam.zoom,
          y = sin(i)*cam.zoom, 
          z = 0.3
        ), 
        center = list(
          x = 0, 
          y = 0, 
          z = 0
        )
        
      )
      
      
    )
    )
  graph
  
}
```

I am very new to plotly, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest the rgl package. I've been able to do exactly this. There's a bit of a learning curve if you haven't worked with htmlwidgets before. But that should provide the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I'm using plotly for my whole app because I have been able to add in planes and meshes. The interactive plots it produces are great. I definitely need to continue with plotly. But thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reuse most of the JS code via `htmlwidgets::onRender`. You tagged the question [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) - wrapped it in an app accordingly:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("graph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  N <- 100
  x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
  y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
  z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
  luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      type = "scatter3d",
      mode = "markers",
      data = luci.frame,
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      z = ~ z
    ) %>%
      layout(scene = list(camera = list(
        eye = list(
          x = 1.25,
          y = 1.25,
          z = 1.25
        ),
        center = list(x = 0,
                      y = 0,
                      z = 0)
      ))) %>%
      onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 180);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result1]

---

The same can be done via `plotlyProxy` without additional JS - but it's not as smooth:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("graph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  N <- 100
  x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
  y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
  z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
  luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)
  
  mySequence <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.1)
  
  cam.zoom = 2
  # ver.angle = 0
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      type = "scatter3d",
      mode = "markers",
      data = luci.frame,
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      z = ~ z
    ) %>%
      layout(scene = list(camera = list(
        eye = list(
          x = cos(mySequence[1]) * cam.zoom,
          y = sin(mySequence[1]) * cam.zoom,
          z = 0.3
        ),
        center = list(x = 0,
                      y = 0,
                      z = 0)
      )))
  })
  
  myPlotlyProxy <- plotlyProxy("graph")
  count <- reactiveVal(1L)
  
  observe({
    invalidateLater(100)
    plotlyProxyInvoke(myPlotlyProxy, "relayout", list(scene = list(camera = list(
      eye = list(
        x = cos(mySequence[isolate(count())]) * cam.zoom,
        y = sin(mySequence[isolate(count())]) * cam.zoom,
        z = 0.3
      ),
      center = list(x = 0,
                    y = 0,
                    z = 0)
    ))))
    
    isolate(count(count()+1))
    
    if(count() > length(mySequence)){
      count(1L)  
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result2]

Comment: This first solution looks excellent, but I can't get it working in an Rmarkdown (Hugo website) application. Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd recommend posting a separat question regarding this. It's hard to help without a reproducible example.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072291/9841389) it is shown how to save this as a standalone HTML file.