# How to save animation rendered by htmlwidgets::onRender() as video or gif files

Tags: r, shiny

How to save [this animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110647/how-to-rotate-3d-plotly-continuous-for-r-shiny-app/) to video or gif ? The 3d animation is very nice !

Sorry for opening a new question post, because I am a new user of stackoverflow and my reputation score is not enough to add comments to the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110647/how-to-rotate-3d-plotly-continuous-for-r-shiny-app/).

Comment: Try `GifCam`.  It works great for me.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried GifCam, it works great, but I would like to know how to save it with codes.

Comment: Did you figure this out? @leopoldliu