# How to rotate 3D Plotly in R, update?

Tags: r, animation, plotly, r-plotly

I want to make an animated plot with a 3D surface

I was trying to replicate this example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66117098/11555164

But I was unable to make it work, is not rotating

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("graph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  N <- 100
  x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
  y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
  z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
  luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      type = "scatter3d",
      mode = "markers",
      data = luci.frame,
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      z = ~ z
    ) %>%
      layout(scene = list(camera = list(
        eye = list(
          x = 1.25,
          y = 1.25,
          z = 1.25
        ),
        center = list(x = 0,
                      y = 0,
                      z = 0)
      ))) %>%
      onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.plot(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 180);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't get any error in the console of Rstudio

I also try to isolate the code, and avoid the use of Shiny (to save it as HTML)
And in Chrome, I get and rendering error when opening the Debugging

[image: Chrome error]

This is the second code (without shiny)

```
#library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)

plot_ly(
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "markers",
  data = luci.frame,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  z = ~ z
) %>%
  layout(scene = list(camera = list(
    eye = list(
      x = 1.25,
      y = 1.25,
      z = 1.25
    ),
    center = list(x = 0,
                  y = 0,
                  z = 0)
  ))) %>%
  onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.plot(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 180);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")
```

Im missing something on onRender?

---

Update:
Thanks to @ismirsehregal for the update in the change of `Plotly.plot` to `Plotly.update`
You can check the accepted answer

In case you need the version without Shiny, you can use this code

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)

PLT <- plot_ly(
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "markers",
  data = luci.frame,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  z = ~ z
) %>%
  layout(scene = list(camera = list(
    eye = list(
      x = 1.25,
      y = 1.25,
      z = 1.25
    ),
    center = list(x = 0,
                  y = 0,
                  z = 0)
  ))) %>%
  onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 1000);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")

PLT
```

Comment: Your example worked perfectly in Shiny. So, try find error in your server config

Comment: @black_paladin and ppriede which versions of R plotly do you use? R plotly [recently updated](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/master/NEWS.md) the underlying plotly.js library from v1.57.1 to v2.5.1. This includes many breaking changes - this solution might be affected.

Comment: Yep - The Plotly.plot() function used here was [dropped](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-js-2-0/53675).

Comment: plotly 4.10, shiny - 1.7.1

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R plotly 4.10.0 [recently updated](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/master/NEWS.md) the underlying plotly.js library from v1.57.1 to v2.5.1. This includes many breaking changes - With version 2.0 of plotly.js the function [Plotly.plot was dropped](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-js-2-0/53675).

To get back the old behaviour `Plotly.plot` can be replaced by `Plotly.update`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("graph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  N <- 100
  x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
  y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
  z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
  luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)
  
  output$graph <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      type = "scatter3d",
      mode = "markers",
      data = luci.frame,
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      z = ~ z
    ) %>%
      layout(scene = list(camera = list(
        eye = list(
          x = 1.25,
          y = 1.25,
          z = 1.25
        ),
        center = list(x = 0,
                      y = 0,
                      z = 0)
      ))) %>%
      onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 180);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```