# Plot_ly rotate animation in R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to animate a 3D figure being rotated around an axis and print that as a .gif or video format. Could not find a resource to assist, please point me in the right direction. Any input is appreciated. Example figure below:

```
library(plotly)
x <- iris$Sepal.Length
y <- iris$Sepal.Width
z <- iris$Petal.Length
test3d <- plot_ly(type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers",
                  x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken from my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110647/how-to-rotate-3d-plotly-continuous-for-r-shiny-app/66117098#66117098).

We can use the code without [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) and save a standalone HTML file via `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(utils)

N <- 100
x <- rnorm(N, mean = 50, sd = 2.3)
y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 100)
z <- runif(N, min = 4, max = 70)
luci.frame <- data.frame(x, y, z)

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "markers",
  data = luci.frame,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  z = ~ z
) %>%
  layout(scene = list(camera = list(
    eye = list(
      x = 1.25,
      y = 1.25,
      z = 1.25
    ),
    center = list(x = 0,
                  y = 0,
                  z = 0)
  ))) %>%
  onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 180);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(partial_bundle(fig), file = "rotate_scatter3d.HTML", selfcontained = TRUE)

utils::browseURL("rotate_scatter3d.HTML")
```

[image: result]

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in Python Plotly?