# Rstudio -Error: Client error: (401) Unauthorized No such user, can't open files.credentials, ./config etc

Tags: r, plotly

When i run the R code in Rstudio, I get below error. what's wrong?'

```
Error: Client error: (401) Unauthorized     No such user In addition: Warning messages: 1: In open.connection(con, "rb") :   cannot open file '/Users/i073341/.plotly/.credentials': No such file or directory 2: In open.connection(con, "rb") :   cannot open file '/Users/i073341/.plotly/.config': No such file or directory 3: You need a plotly username. See help(signup, package = 'plotly')  4: Couldn't find username  5: In open.connection(con, "rb") :   cannot open file '/Users/i073341/.plotly/.credentials': No such file or directory 6: In open.connection(con, "rb") :   cannot open file '/Users/i073341/.plotly/.config': No such file or directory 7: You need an api_key. See help(signup, package = 'plotly')  8: Couldn't find api_key
```

R code:

```
library("plotly")
a = read.csv('cleanSankey.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
node_names <- unique(c(as.character(a$source), as.character(a$target)))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(a$source, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(a$target, node_names) - 1,
                    value = a$value)



#Plot
p <- plot_ly(type='sankey',
        orientation = "h",
        
        node = list(
          label = node_names,
          color = "grey",
          pad = 15,
          thinkness = 20,
          line = list(color = "grey", width = 0.5)),
 
         link = list(
           source = links$source,
           target = links$target,
           value = links$value))

plotly_IMAGE(p, out_file="out.png")
```

If I remove last row code plotly_IMAGE(p, out_file="out.png"), there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotly_IMAGE` is used to export graphs as static images using [plotly chart studio](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/create/#/). You need an api_key for this to work. See [this](https://plotly.com/r/chart-studio-image-export/) or `help(signup, package = 'plotly')`.

If you want to export static images on your local PC you can use `plotly::save_image(p, "plot.png")`.

For `save_image` to work please consider the following:

> kaleido() requires the kaleido python package to be usable via the
> reticulate package. Here is a recommended way to do the installation:
>
> install.packages('reticulate') reticulate::install_miniconda()
> reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'python-kaleido')
> reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'plotly', channel =
> 'plotly') reticulate::use_miniconda('r-reticulate')

---

As an alternative you could use

`htmlwidgets::saveWidget(partial_bundle(p), file = "plot.HTML", selfcontained = TRUE)`

to save your chart as a standalone HTML file (e.g. as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072291/9841389))

Comment: Thank you. I installed package 'reticulate' successfully in RStudio by code install.packages("reticulate"), but when when I run this code plotly::save_image(p, "plot.png"), RStudio says that - Error in py_module_import(module, convert=convert): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kaleido.'

Comment: Did you run all of the above installation steps successfully?

Comment: I re-checked and missed one install. Now I have run all the installations. but code plotly::save_image(p, "plot.png") still can't be executed successfully, and the error is Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert): SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncacted \UXXXXXXXX escape (<string>, line1)

Comment: the code i run is plotly::save_image(p, "C:\\Users\\I073341\\OneDrive- SAp SE\\plot.png")

Comment: Can you please try: `plot_path <- tempfile(pattern="plot", fileext = ".png"); plotly::save_image(p, plot_path); shell.exec(plot_path)`