# Removing Labels and Downloading Plotly Sunburst Plot R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to create a sunburst plot but can't seem to figure out how to remove the labels. I have included my code below as well as a picture of what the plot looks like.

I also would like to know how I can download this statically, preferably as TIF or PDF. Any suggestions?

```
fig <- plotly::plot_ly(
  labels = c("total", "Discharged", "Admitted", "Transferred", "Direct", "Indirect"),
  parents = c("", "total", "total", "total", "Transferred", "Transferred"),
  values = c(5538, 1044, 4031, 297, 220, 76), 
  type = "sunburst",
  branchvalues = "total", 
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textinfo` parameter to control the text elements associated with each sector.

Run `schema()` and navigate:

object ► traces ► sunburst ► attributes ► textinfo ► flags

for further information.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plotly::plot_ly(
  textinfo = "text",
  text = c("test", "test2", "", "", "", ""),
  labels = c("total", "Discharged", "Admitted", "Transferred", "Direct", "Indirect"),
  parents = c("", "total", "total", "total", "Transferred", "Transferred"),
  values = c(5538, 1044, 4031, 297, 220, 76), 
  type = "sunburst",
  branchvalues = "total", 
)

fig
```

Regarding the download: You can use the modebar to download a png file or use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` to create a standalone HTML file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042818/plot-ly-rotate-animation-in-r/71072291#71072291) is an example.