# Plotly rotation animation and changing camera eye in R

Tags: r, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am having trouble changing the camera eye in my rotating animation of a plotly "scatter3d" plot.

I can specify the camera eye using the `layout` function in the `plotly` R package.

```
fig %>% 
  layout(
    scene = list(
      aspectratio = list(x = 1, y = 1, z = -1),
      camera = list(
        center = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0),
        eye = list(x = -.1, y = .5, z = 1.5)),
      up = list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0),
      xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, range = c(-10, 10),
                   showticklabels = FALSE, title = list(text = "")),
      yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, range = c(-10, 10),
                   showticklabels = FALSE, title = list(text = "")),
      zaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, range = c(-10, 10),
                   showticklabels = FALSE, title = list(text = "")),
      dragmode = "turntable",
      aspectmode='cube'#,
      #annotations = annots
    ), margin = list(t = 30, r = 30, l = 30, b = 30, padding = 2))%>%
```

Where `fig` is a "plotly" "htmlwidget" of type "scatter3d"

yielding the following plot: *plot with correct camera eye*

[image]

I added the following code with the `htmlwidget` package to create a rotating animation but the camera eye gets reset.

```
%>%
  
  onRender(
    '
  function(el, x) {
    var id = el.getAttribute("id");
    var gd = document.getElementById(id);
    Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
    
    function attach() {
      var cnt = 0;
      
      function run() {
        rotate("scene", Math.PI / 360);
        requestAnimationFrame(run);
      } 
      run();
      
      function rotate(id, angle) {
        var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye;
        var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
        rtz.t += angle;
        
        var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
        Plotly.relayout(gd, id + ".camera.eye", eye1)
      }
      
      function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
        return {
          r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
          t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
          z: xyz.z
        };
      }
      
      function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
        return {
          x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
          y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
          z: rtz.z
        };
      }
    }
  }
  '
  )
```

Yeilding the following animation: *rotating plot with unfavorable camera eye*

[image]

I would really like for the rotation to be from the first camera eye and spin. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: It's always best to make your questions reproducible, however, without your data, I just used `mtcars` and applied your function. It starts at the exact `eye` that was set. I'm wondering if the axes rotation not giving you the perspective you wanted... For example, change your eye to `list(x = -1.5, y = .5, z = .1)` and use your `onRender` call, it's going to rotate very differently, but like the original eye, it starts exactly where it was before adding the rotation. After looking at it this way, do you understand what I mean about perspective? Is that what you want to change in your outcome?

Comment: @Kat Thank you so much for helping me out with this. I think I understand what you mean by the perspective. I intentionally set the eye `eye = list(x = -.1, y = .5, z = 1.5))` in the `layout` function. The `onRender` function changes it back to default and rotates from there. I would like to keep the green on top and the blue and pink clusters on bottom while spinning, if that makes sense. It seems as though I need to adjust something in the `onRender` function that I pulled from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042818/plot-ly-rotate-animation-in-r).

Comment: Are you saying that instead of spinning like a clock, you want it to spin like a top? (Just trying to make sure I understand.) Right now you're spinning about the z-axis, do you want to spin about the y or x? BTW, when I run this it doesn't start by resetting the eye, no matter what settings I use. It might be worth it to comment out the settings that hide the grid and see how the grid moves, both with and without the `onRender`.

Comment: @Kat, I removed the settings to hide the grid, and the eye did not reset, just as you suggested. I want it to spin like a top with the green cluster remaining on top; thank you for helping me express this crucial point. I believe that means that I would like it to spin about the y-axis.