# Plotly rotate animation in Python to HTML file

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, igraph, plotly-python

I am trying to animate a 3D scatterplot in Plotly being rotated around an axis and save the output as html.

[The only resource I found is done in R.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71072291/5433663)

Wondering if anyone has any resources on doing it in Python?

What I have done so far:

```
import igraph as ig
import networkx as nx
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

# get data
with urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/miserables.json") as response:
    body = response.read()
data = json.loads(body)

# 3D graph layout
N=len(data['nodes'])
L=len(data['links'])
Edges=[(data['links'][k]['source'], data['links'][k]['target']) for k in range(L)]
G=ig.Graph(Edges, directed=False)
labels=[]
group=[]
for node in data['nodes']:
    labels.append(node['name'])
    group.append(node['group'])
layt=G.layout('kk', dim=3)
Xn=[layt[k][0] for k in range(N)]# x-coordinates of nodes
Yn=[layt[k][1] for k in range(N)]# y-coordinates
Zn=[layt[k][2] for k in range(N)]# z-coordinates
Xe=[]
Ye=[]
Ze=[]
for e in Edges:
    Xe+=[layt[e[0]][0],layt[e[1]][0], None]# x-coordinates of edge ends
    Ye+=[layt[e[0]][1],layt[e[1]][1], None]
    Ze+=[layt[e[0]][2],layt[e[1]][2], None]

# Plotly Plot
trace1=go.Scatter3d(x=Xe,
               y=Ye,
               z=Ze,
               mode='lines',
               line=dict(color='rgb(125,125,125)', width=1),
               hoverinfo='none'
               )

trace2=go.Scatter3d(x=Xn,
               y=Yn,
               z=Zn,
               mode='markers',
               name='actors',
               marker=dict(symbol='circle',
                             size=6,
                             color=group,
                             colorscale='Viridis',
                             line=dict(color='rgb(50,50,50)', width=0.5)
                             ),
               text=labels,
               hoverinfo='text'
               )

axis=dict(showbackground=False,
          showline=False,
          zeroline=False,
          showgrid=False,
          showticklabels=False,
          title=''
          )

layout = go.Layout(
         title="Network of coappearances of characters in Victor Hugo's novel<br> Les Miserables (3D visualization)",
         width=1000,
         height=1000,
         showlegend=False,
         scene=dict(
             xaxis=dict(axis),
             yaxis=dict(axis),
             zaxis=dict(axis),
        ),
     margin=dict(
        t=100
    ),
    hovermode='closest',
    annotations=[
           dict(
           showarrow=False,
            text="Data source: <a href='http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/miserables.json'>[1] miserables.json</a>",
            xref='paper',
            yref='paper',
            x=0,
            y=0.1,
            xanchor='left',
            yanchor='bottom',
            font=dict(
            size=14
            )
            )
        ],    )

data_trace=[trace1, trace2]
fig=go.Figure(data=data_trace, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

To make it rotate, I have done the following:

```
x_eye = -1.25
y_eye = 2
z_eye = 0.5

fig.update_layout(
         title='Animation Test',
         width=1000,
         height=1000,
         scene_camera_eye=dict(x=x_eye, y=y_eye, z=z_eye),
         updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                  showactive=False,
                  y=1,
                  x=0.8,
                  xanchor='left',
                  yanchor='bottom',
                  pad=dict(t=45, r=10),
                  buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                 method='animate',
                                 args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=5, redraw=True), 
                                                             transition=dict(duration=0),
                                                             fromcurrent=True,
                                                             # mode='immediate'
                                                            )]
                                            )
                                      ]
                              )
                        ]
)


def rotate_z(x, y, z, theta):
    w = x+1j*y
    return np.real(np.exp(1j*theta)*w), np.imag(np.exp(1j*theta)*w), z

frames=[]
for t in np.arange(0, 6.26, 0.1):
    xe, ye, ze = rotate_z(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, -t)
    frames.append(go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze))))
fig.frames=frames
fig.write_html("./file.html")
fig.show()
```

It rotates in the notebook, but when viewing the html file, it doesn't work and is very laggy.